# Dinamically create Javascript function with current variable values

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to ask correctly what I need, so let me try..

How can I pass a current variable content (literal) to a function dinamically created?

Maybe with this following code you understand better:

```
function MyClass(){

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    this['show' + i] = function(){
      alert('You called show' + i);
    };
  }
}

var obj = new MyClass();

obj.show3();
```

What I would like to be displayed in alert is "You called show3" instead of "show11".

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. @Franceso, I liked your answer, however kaigorodov's is simpler, so I marked it as answer ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mechanism called binding in JavaScript. You can bind scope and any variables to the function in order to use them inside function. Scope will define `this` keyword inside function. All other binded variables will be available as arguments thus `i` variable in this example will have not a global but local scope and have a value passed in function creation.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    this['show' + i] = function(i){
      alert('You called show' + i);
    }.bind(this,i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since javascript doesn't have a block scope (until `let` in ECMAScript 6) your original function will be bound with the same value of i. 
Calling another that generate itself a new function you avoid that and you give to i different values.

```
function MyClass() {

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    this['show' + i] = myFunc(i);
  }
}

function myFunc(i) {
    return function() {
       alert(i);
    }
}

var obj = new MyClass();

obj.show3();
```